# IE6 position:absolute in relative container resizing

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-position, resize

I have this bug in IE6. I've showed it here http://fiddle.jshell.net/bfXGC/2. When you increase height of container, then position of absolute block updates to the bottom of container. When you increase height of inner content, then position of absolute block doesn't updates. How can I fix this behaviour in IE6

Comment: I've found universal expression ( it uses jQuery ): bottom:auto;top:expression( $(this).parent().outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight() )

Answer (score 2):

Only way i could get this to work is to set the css `top` value on the absolute div each time you update:

```
$("div.absolute").css("top", $(".inner").height());
```

A working example is available here. http://fiddle.jshell.net/bfXGC/14/

Comment: Almost the same answer with the same formatting within 7 seconds of each other :)

Comment: @Kukman: It looks like you're trying to use a CSS expression to apply this fix. Are you using jQuery on your actual page?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify if a JavaScript fix is acceptable, but if it is, this works:

```
$('.absolute').css('position', 'static').css('position', 'absolute');
```

Yes, that is just reapplying `position: absolute`. It *forces* IE6 to recalculate.

**See:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/bfXGC/15/